# Explanation on network transfer bit rate R

Tags: networking, bitrate

Bit Rate `R` usually refers to:

> Number of bits transferred in unit of network time on a link **L**.

I am curious on the sending direction of `R`. Because data on link `L` has two directions.
Does R means aggregate bits transferred in the two directions?

Another question is link `L` can send data in a single direction?

I have bought a network wire of 100 `Mbps`. So this means that I can send/receive at 100Mbps rate?

Also we usually heard of bi-directional working like FTP protocol. What does this bi-directional mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit rates are almost always specified in terms of the rate from the sender to the receiver, with the implication that to get the maximum round-trip bit rate, you double the result.  When this isn't correct (*e.g.*, [Asymmertic DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADSL), [satellite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_internet) or [cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_modem) Internet), the bit rates will always be specified for both directions.

Links are almost always conceptually bi-directional, although not always (*e.g.*, [satellite Internet access sometimes is download-only, with upload via telephone lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_internet#One-way_receive.2C_with_terrestrial_transmit)), but from a physical perspective, a link is always unidirectional at a single point in time, and often always unidirectional.

Your "network wire of 100 Mbps" doesn't exist.  What you bought was a [CAT-5 Ethernet cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT-5), which contains 8 wires.  No single one of them can carry a 100Mbps signal, but they are used in combination to build up the full signal rate.

As to FTP, that's a completely different question, and the "bi-directional" is unrelated to all of this.

Comment: Thanks! In network, we also talk about duplex like full duplex, half duplex. Full duplex means simultaneously transmission in two directions. Half duplex means only one end can send while the other end listens. I want to know, in which context should we talk about duplex. Is it a protocol thing, or a hardware thing? Twisted cable (like CAT-5 Ethernet cable) is duplex or not? How can we decide whether the "thing" is duplex or not?